# Find avg of Salary , Departmnent wise , SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to find the avg salary from the below table, department wise without a join. The result should have Name, Age, Department, and avg_salary per department

[image]

Using a self join as below, is one way I can get the desired output. WOuld like to know option without using a self join.

```
SELECT name,age, department,avg.avg_salary
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT department, avg(salary) as avg_salary
 FROM Table1 GROUP by department) avg
ON avg.department = table1.department
```

Comment: Do you think it's here?  What did you try to find it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: When your question is about how to do it in MySQL, you could also have posted something like: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=014ca6af509ab4719c1852dc56848239, and not the picture...

Comment: On one hand, you'd like to group several users (i.e. a department) to find an average salary. On the other hand, you'd like your resulting table to have a `Name` and an `Age`. How can a **group** of users have a name and an age?

Comment: ...and, why are you specifically opposed to a join?

Comment: The docs even give an example of how to get the average test_score, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_avg.   what did you try to get the average salary?

Comment: Please TEXT, no PICTURES!

Comment: HINT: In the docs, where they describe AVG(), there is also a link to [12.21.2 Window Function Concepts and Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html).  Please read that paragraph, and you will know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Luuk  - the link above helped!

Comment: What kind of SQL database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

No platform tagged, but I think most platforms have window functions that you can use like so:

### Average Salary Using AVG() Window Function

```
SELECT name
      ,age
      ,department
      ,AVG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY department) AS avg_salary
FROM Table1
```